# Consulta agrupada con distintos contadores

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes, espero esten bien.
Tengo un problema con una consulta SQL que pinta a ser sencilla pero creo que no lo es, tengo la siguiente tabla con esta información:

```
id   pais    sexo
== ========  ====
 1 Venezuela F
 2 Venezuela F
 3 Venezuela M
 4 Colombia  F
 5 Colombia  F
 6 Colombia  F
 7 Colombia  M
 8 Brasil    F
 9 Brasil    F
```

Debo hacer una consulta, que me devuelva la información de esta forma:

```
pais      femenino masculino
========= ======== =========
Venezuela        2         1
Colombia         3         1
Brasil           2         0
```

Yo he pensando algo así:

```
SELECT count(per1.sexo), count(per2.sexo), per1.pais, per2.pais
FROM `personas` per1,`personas` per2
WHERE 
per1.sexo = "F"
AND per2.sexo = "M"
group by(per1.pais)
```

pero no es la solución y no me funciona, por favor si pueden ayudarme, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT pais,
   sum(case when sexo = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) Masculino,
   sum(case when sexo = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) Femenino
FROM personas
GROUP BY pais;
```

Y te devolverá

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| pais     | Masculino| Femenino |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Venezuela| 0        |        2 |
| Colombia | 3        |        1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Para obtener el resultado tal cual lo deseas en una tabla lo puedes realizar con subconsultas:

```
SELECT pais, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Personas P1 WHERE P1.pais = P.pais AND sexo = 'F') AS Femenino,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Personas P1 WHERE P1.pais = P.pais AND sexo = 'M') AS Masculino
FROM Personas P
GROUP BY Pais
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
pais                      Femenino    Masculino
------------------------- ----------- -----------
BRASIL                    2           0
COLOMBIA                  3           1
VENEZUELA                 2           1
```

Comment: me ahorraria esos select count junto con los WHERE con el sum

Comment: Ejecuté el Plan de Ejecución Estimado para ambas consultas y tienes razón, es más óptima tu consulta

Answer (score 3):

Esta consulta es prácticamente lo mismo que @sioesi, solo que usa [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

```
SELECT pais AS Pais,
   SUM(IF(sexo = 'M', 1, 0)) AS Masculino,
   SUM(IF(sexo = 'F', 1, 0)) AS Femenino
FROM personas
GROUP BY pais
ORDER BY pais ASC
```

El resultado sera:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Pais      | Masculino | Femenino |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
| BRASIL    |         0 |        2 |
| COLOMBIA  |         1 |        3 |
| VENEZUELA |         1 |        2 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

> **Nota**: Para que la consulta funcione correctamente, la columna `pais`, debe tener una cotejamiento `case insensitive`, por ejemplo `latin1_general_ci`.

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar a las excelentes respuestas de @sioesi y @Marcos Gallardo, te dejo otra opción que es un poco más compacta, pero simpre usando un SQL estándar que te puede servir en otras bases de datos también y que es completamente equivalente en rendimiento a sus respuestas. La diferencia es simplemente que uso la función `COUNT` en vez de `SUM` para no tener que escribir una expresión `ELSE`:

```
select pais,
       count(case when sexo = 'M' then 1 end) as masculino,
       count(case when sexo = 'F' then 1 end) as femenino
  from personas
 group by pais
```

Lo que sí te sugiero es de evitar de usar sub consultas para este problema. Puede parecer la forma mas obvia y sencilla de ejecutar la sentencia, pero no es muy eficiente y no es necesario.

**Nota adicional**

Aunque funcione, te sugiero de evitar usar las comillas dobles para delimitar cadenas como `M` y `F`. No es estándar hacerlo de esa manera. Mas bien, favorece usar las comillas simples, como de hecho todos lo han hecho en las respuestas publicadas a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta consulta

```
SELECT p.pais, count(f.sexo) as femenino, count(m.sexo) as masculino
FROM personas p
LEFT JOIN personas m on  (m.pais = p.pais and m.sexo = 'M')
LEFT JOIN personas f on  (f.pais = p.pais and f.sexo = 'F')
GROUP BY p.pais
```

Comment: Al probar tu consulta no se obtienen los resultados adecuados. Al realizar el LEFT JOIN obligas a que haga match con la columna `sexo`, la cual, por ejemplo, en el caso del país Brasil no existe