# obtener el ultimo insert ingresado sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

tengo una base de datos sql server 2012, donde tengo una tabla que contiene un campo datetime, y lo que necesito es obtener el ultimo insert que se hizo, tengo la siguiente tabla y espero que puedan ayudarme

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|cod_reporte|nombre_ruta |email   |tipo        |descripcion |fecha    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| int       | varchar    |varchar |varchar     |varchar     |datetime |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

lo que necesito exactamente es obtener el ultimo insert, especificando una ruta

ejemplo: ruta 1= ..... .....

ruta 2= ..... ....

espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: No entiendo la lógica de lo que buscas. Por favor incluye un ejemplo con datos para ayudarnos a entender lo que buscas.

Comment: ¿A través de una consulta?

Comment: @Garrizano si, es lo que necesito

Comment: ¿ruta1 y ruta 2 de dónde los sacas?

Comment: @Garrizano, del nombre ruta, el campo que dibuje en la tablita

Comment: ¿El último insert es el que tiene la fecha más alta?

Comment: Cuando haces preguntas de este tipo, es buena idea incluir una muestra de los datos de entrada y de los de salida. Dale una mirada a [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/37861/21) para inspirarte en cómo publicar tus datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que, para una ruta en particular, quieres devolver el registro con la fecha más reciente. Si esto es lo que quieres, puedes usar `TOP 1` combinado con un `ORDER BY` por la columna `fecha`.

```
select top 1 *
  from tabla
 where nombre_ruta = 'valor_ruta'
 order by fecha desc
```

Aquí te dejo otras opciones que puedes emplear también usando subconsultas, o la función ventana `row_number()`. Pero la opción con el `TOP 1` es la más sencilla:

```
select *
  from tabla t
 where t.nombre_ruta = 'valor_ruta'
   and t.fecha = (select max(t2.fecha)
                    from tabla t2
                   where t2.nombre_ruta = t.nombre_ruta)

select t.*
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (order by t.fecha desc) as rn
          from tabla t
         where t.nombre_ruta = 'valor_ruta') t
 where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: Tenia la misma respuesta, excelente.

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes obtener con

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Esto te traerá el último `Id` insertado

Comment: pero con el id, obtendre el de un id especifico, no me entregare el ultimo de una ruta en especifico

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con algo así:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM TU_TABLA WHERE NOMBRE_RUTA="RUTA1" ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```

Con esta consulta obtienes un registro `TOP 1` de TU_TABLA donde el NOMBRE_RUTA sea igual al nombre de ruta que necesites la cual se ordena por la FECHA de firma descendente, de mayor a menor.

Comment: ¿podrías explicar cómo esto responde a la pregunta? ¿Cómo es que esta sentencia obtendría el último insert?