# Conocer el ultimo precio de productos Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de productos en donde estan sus caracteristicas y otra tabla "db_stock" en donde se gestionan las actividades de los productos. Estas actividades pueden variar el precio de compra o precio de venta de los productos, incluso varias veces al dia.

He buscado en Stackoverflow *(Por ej. [obtener el ultimo insert ingresado sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38454/obtener-el-ultimo-insert-ingresado-sql))* y otras paginas pero lo que mas se me acerca es utilizar el top 1, order by... limit 1, having max(fecha), selec max(fecha) pero no se si los he utilizado mal pero no logro construir la sentencia.

He creado tablas y vistas para ver el ultimo registro hecho, y luego unir el id de registro y extraer los precios pero algo hago mal y me devuelve otras fechas... incluso fechas del tipo 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ... (Eso ultimo utilizando el select max o having max fecha.

Aqui alguno de ejemplos fallidos: (Utilizo el producto 3115 como prueba unitaria ya que un producto puede tener muchos registro de actividades y cambio de precios) *Son aproximadamente 19.000 productos y muchisimos  registros mas en stock*

```
    create view ultimosPrecios as 
select idproductos, cproveedor, csalida 
from db_stock
where max(registro) and cproveedor != "" and csalida != "";

create view ultimosPrecios5 as 
select idproducto, cproveedor, csalida,  max(registro)
from db_stock
where  cproveedor != "" and csalida != "" and cproveedor != 0 and csalida != 0
group by idproducto;

select count(a.idproducto),a.idproducto from (
SELECT distinct idproducto
FROM db_stock)a
GROUP BY idproducto;

create view ultimoReg as 
SELECT distinct idproducto, max(registro)
FROM db_stock
GROUP BY idproducto;

SELECT DISTINCT id, idproducto, csalida, cproveedor, MAX( registro ) 
FROM db_stock
WHERE cproveedor !=  ""
AND csalida !=  ""
AND cproveedor !=0
AND csalida !=0
AND idproducto =  '3115'
GROUP BY idproducto
LIMIT 0 , 30

SELECT DISTINCT id, idproducto, b.cproveedor, MAX( a.registro )
FROM db_stock a inner join (select cproveedor, registro
from db_stock )b 
ON a.registro = b.registro 
WHERE a.idproducto =  '3115'
GROUP BY a.idproducto
LIMIT 0 , 300

create view vista_preciosPro as
SELECT ur.id, ur.idproducto, sp.csalida, sp.cproveedor 
FROM db_stock sp inner join ultimoReg ur ON sp.id = ur.id;
```

Chicos, aun no puedo solucion mi problema y ya llevo ocmo 4 dias con esto. Me parece super simple sin embargo no hayo solucion. Pedi autorizacion para eliminar y trabajar con solo datos que tengan registros correctos y dentro del 2017, y aun asi no doy con la solucion.

Comment: podrias agregar las estrucutras de tus tablas y un pequeño ejemplo de datos y cual deberia ser el resultado?

Comment: No se entiende bien la cuestión. ¿Tienes una tabla donde almacenas precios de productos y quieres saber cuál es el último precio que se le ha asignado a un producto específico? Si la tabla de precios tiene una columna datetime sería la columna ideal para hacerlo. En MySQL existen funciones para obtener la fecha más elevada dentro de una columna de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreto que lo que queres hacer es mostrar el último precio de la tabla "db_stock" si es asi, la tabla me imagino que tiene un "id" autonumérico. En caso de ser así, lo único que deberías hacer es en el `where` de cada consulta poner un `IN` de "id" a la misma consulta, pero devolvés "max(id)". proba de esa forma, a continuación te pongo el ejemplo:

```
create view ultimosPrecios as 
select idproductos, cproveedor, csalida 
from db_stock
where cproveedor != "" and csalida != ""
and id in (select max(id) from db_stock
where cproveedor != "" and csalida != "");
```

---

Por otro lado, esta consulta debería devolverte el último registro insertado para un producto determinado.

Esto va a funcionar siempre y cuando en él esté el último precio.

```
create view ultimosPrecios as 
select a.idproductos, a.cproveedor, a.csalida 
from db_stock a
where a.cproveedor != "" and a.csalida != ""
and a.id in (select max(b.id) from db_stock b
where a.idproductos = b.idproductos);
```

Comment: he probado tu consulto y solo devuelve un registro con datos erroneos.

Comment: Mmm bien, el tema es que no sabemos la estructura de tus tablas, ni la relacion de las mismas, fijate de esta forma, te explico de paso la consulta. La pongo abajo asi se ve el codigo.

Comment: @Nico gracias por eliminar tu otra respuesta. Me refería a editar tu respuesta original, no agregarlo como comentario. Recién copié el contenido. Podrás editar las publicaciones las veces que sean necesarias

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos, soy nuevo y no sabia las formas de responder, ahora elimino el comentario anterior. Saludos.